# Jasper Reports HTML markup doenst work for XML field

Tags: html, xml, jasper-reports

I would need a little help around my new Jasper Report.
It uses xml file as datasource:

```
<Krediti xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Kredit>
    <VrstaPosla>Integer viverra volutpat enim ac <b>consectetur</b>. Proin eu ex interdum, lacinia lorem a, euismod elit. Pellentesque sit amet justo venenatis, consequat magna id, commodo metus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Praesent ipsum sem, lacinia vel blandit nec, porta in elit. Nullam volutpat vestibulum imperdiet. Etiam egestas dui risus, a euismod justo luctus et. Praesent sed dolor scelerisque, vehicula arcu sit amet, dapibus tellus. Donec et scelerisque orci. Ut ante diam, congue vitae libero at, bibendum feugiat metus. Suspendisse lobortis imperdiet facilisis. Etiam id massa tempor, maximus dui bibendum, mattis lectus.!!!</VrstaPosla>
    <SifraKredita>11000000</SifraKredita>
</Kredit>
```

I would like to print text which is in b tags in bold. In my example that would be word consectetur.

In order to do that I set field property markup to html but still doesn't work.

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="3" y="3" width="552" height="52" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="7826a459-9146-47ec-a500-32dbf81e5cdd"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="html"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{VrstaPosla}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

If I put text directly into field it is working:

```
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="3" y="3" width="552" height="52" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="7826a459-9146-47ec-a500-32dbf81e5cdd"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="html"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Text <b>is bolded</b>"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

Could it be that report strips all tags which comes from XML field?

Regards,
Igor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked and yes, you cannot use html tags inside xml which is source to the report cause report see is like a node. If I change it to CSV it works.

```
Year,Make,Model,Description,Price
1997,Ford <i><b>Krepko</b></i>,E350,"ac, abs, moon",3000.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition""","",4900.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition, Very Large""",,5000.00
1996,Jeep,Grand Cherokee,"MUST SELL! air, moon roof, loaded",4799.00
```

Regards,

Igor